# How to connect a pyqtSignal from a class inside one module to a pyqtSlot in a class inside another module?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots

I have a file `wizard.py`:

```python
class MyWizard(QWizard):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...

class PageOne(QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...

class FinalPage(QWizardPage):
    populateTable = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...

    def initializePage(self):
        finish_button = self.wizard().button(QWizard.FinishButton)
        finish_button.clicked.connect(self.populateTable.emit)
```

and another file `main_ui.py`:

```python
import wizard

class UiMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.table = QTableView(self)
        # ...

        self.my_wizard = wizard.MyWizard()
        self.my_wizard.exec_()
        # ...

        self.final_page = wizard.FinalPage()
        self.final_page.connect(self.populate_table)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def populate_table(self):
        # fill some data into self.table
```

The `main_ui` module imports the `wizard` module and launches the wizard.

After launching the wizard, I want to call the `populate_table()` method in `main_ui.py` every time I close the wizard on the final page when clicking the wizard's finish button.

I tried emitting a `pyqtSignal()` from the wizard and connect it to `UiMainWindow`'s `populate_table()` method, but it doesn't seem to recieve the signal. I have used the `@pyqtSlot()` decorator on `populate_table()`, but that doesen't work, too.

However, emitting a signal from a custom class *inside* `main_ui.py` which I connected to `populate_table()` works fine. But a signal from a class inside `wizard.py` is not being recieved.

**My question:**

Is there a way to connect a *signal from a class in one module* to the *method of a class in another module*?

Comment: What do you mean by "emitting a `pyqtSignal()"? I don't see any pyqtSignal declaration in your classes. Qt signals **must** be declared in class definitions.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: @Joey change to `self.final_page.populateTable.connect(self.populate_table)`

Comment: @Joey also change to `finish_button.clicked.connect(self.populateTable)`

Comment: @Joey the connection syntax is: `sender.signal.connect(obj.slot)`

Comment: @Joey: In the example you posted, `self.final_page = wizard.FinalPage()` will create a new instance of `FinalPage` which is independent of the final page in `self.my_wizard`. You would need to connect the slot to the signal of the `FinalPage` instance that is displayed in the `self.my_wizard`. You are probably better off moving the signal `populateTable` from `FinalPage` to `Wizard` and connect `self.my_wizard.populateTable` to `self.populate_table` in `UiMainWindow`.

Comment: @Heike Your suggestion finally led me to the solution. Defining the signal in `MyWizard` instead of in `FinalPage` and then connecting `self.my_wizard.populateTable` to the `self.populate_table` method in `UiMainwindow` works. I have formulated an answer to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Heike, the signal must be defined in `MyWizard` instead of in `FinalPage`.

Then the `self.my_wizard.populateTable` signal must be connected to the `self.populate_table` method in `UiMainwindow`.

It was already a bad idea to want to use the `finish_button` in `FinalPage` to emit the signal, because previously I already have had connected the `finish_button` with `self.wizard().restart()` which is necessary, since the wizard is executed from `UiMainwindow`. That means that *without* calling `self.wizard().restart()`, the wizard would always respawn on the last active page when executed next time (i.e. on `FinalPage`).

So, to send the signal, I now call `self.wizard().populateTable.emit()` in the `initializePage` method of `FinalPage` and then connect it as described above, inside `UiMainWindow` with the `populate_table` method.

---

I have rewritten the code accordingly:

**wizard.py**

```python
class MyWizard(QWizard):
    populateTable = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...

class PageOne(QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...

class FinalPage(QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...

    def initializePage(self):
        # need to keep finish_button connected to self.wizard().restart()
        finish_button = self.wizard().button(QWizard.FinishButton)
        finish_button.clicked.connect(self.wizard().restart)

        # emit the signal when switching to the last page
        self.wizard().populateTable.emit()
```

**main_ui.py**

```python
import wizard

class UiMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.table = QTableView(self)
        # ...

        self.my_wizard = wizard.MyWizard()
        self.my_wizard.populateTable.connect(self.populate_table)
        # ...

    def populate_table(self):
        # update the content in self.table
```